# Proof that countable union of countable sets is valid?

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Analysis beginner here. Of course this has been asked many times, but all the others proofs I found were slightly different from what I have. So I was just wondering whether this is valid, and in particular, if it is equivalent to the diagonal argument that is found in Rudin, for example. I think so, but I am not sure. Thank you!

Let $A_1$, $A_2$, ... be a sequence of countable sets. Then for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $A_i = \{a_{i,1},a_{i,2},...\}$.

Define $B=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$. For each element $b\in B$, we have $b \in A_i$ for at least one $i$, so $b = a_{i,j}$ for some positive integers $i,j$.

Pick some element of $B$ and call it $b_k$. Define $f(k) = min\{ i \in \mathbb{N}: b_k \in A_i \}$ and $g(k, f(k)) = \{j \in \mathbb{N}: b_k = a_{f(k),j} \}$

Then define the sequence $k \rightarrow b_k$ by $\{b_1, b_2, ...\}=\{a_{f(1),g(1,f(1))},a_{f(2),g(2,f(2))},...$}. This sequence contains each element of $B$ exactly once, so $B$ is countable.

Answer (score 2):

Calling $b_k$ your element of $B$ obscures evertything. Better call it $b.$ And replace your definition of $f$ by $f(b) =\min\{ i \in \mathbb{N}: b \in A_i \}.$ And your definition of $g$ by $g(b) =\min \{j \in \mathbb{N}: b= a_{f(b),j} \}.$ And $\{b_1, b_2, ...\}=\{a_{f(1),g(1,f(1))},a_{f(2),g(2,f(2))},\dots\}$ by $B=\{a_{f(b),g(b)}:b\in B\}.$ But then, I think you gained nothing, do you?

Comment: After thinking about it some more, I am afraid that you're right. I wrote $b_k$ in order to indicate that the sequence $k \rightarrow b_k$ could be created by iterating through the elements of $B$: pick one element and call it $b_1$, then pick another one and call it $b_2$, etc. But assuming that such a list would exhaust the elements of B is already assuming that $B$ is countable, so the reasoning is circular.